# Using Simple ITK to find bounding box

Tags: python, itk, simpleitk

How can I capture the bounding box from the 3D mask by using Simple ITK in python?
The ITK has the bounding box function, but I couldn't find similar function in SITK.

Comment: What is the specific ITK class and method you found in ITK? Are you looking for a axis aligned bounding box or an oriented bounding box?

Comment: UPDATE: LabelStatisticsImageFilter has functions to do it in SITK

Answer (score 1):

You need a LabelShapeStatisticsImageFilter, and after Execute you can get the BoundingBox around certain values.
In case of several masks you can iterate on `range(1,labelimfilter.GetNumberOfLabels()+1)`.
(Works this way because you can't calculate BoundingBox on the value 0.)

```
import SimpleITK as sitk

bbox=[]

labelimfilter=sitk.LabelShapeStatisticsImageFilter()
labelimfilter.Execute(yourmaskimage)
for i in range(1,labelimfilter.GetNumberOfLabels()+1):
    box=labelimfilter.GetBoundingBox(i)
    bbox.append(box)
```

This will return the bounding box coordinates in [xstart, ystart, zstart, xsize, ysize, zsize] order